# How to do an evaluation within Sparx EA's RTF generator?

Tags: generator, rtf

I'm using Sparx EA (version 9.3) and am looking to use the RTF generator to get some info out of our repository.  I would like to conditionally add and format some data, as well as show some calculated data.  (i.e. say word length, number of letters in a field, etc)

How on earth can this be done?  I just can't seem to see where or how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up looking at the problem from another direction.  Using a script to iterate through the object and through the script writing evaluations into the "CreateDocumentGenerator".  Messy but is getting the outcome.